# jquery remove hover remove class name

Tags: jquery, class, hover

I have this jQuery code that replaces the class name `<li class="cat">` with `<li class="cat show">` on hover. After I hover out it remains the same. What is wrong with the `removeClass` code?

***JS***

```
jQuery(".cat").hover(function({
    jQuery(this).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show');
});
```

***HTML***

```
<ul> 
    <li class="cat"><a>Motors</a>    
        <ul> 
            <li>Top categories</li> 
            <li> <a href="" aria-haspopup="false">Cars</a></li>
            <li> <a href="" aria-haspopup="false">Motorcycles</a></li> 
            <li> <a href="" aria-haspopup="false">Parts</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a de ja vu post!

Comment: Just use toggleClass -> http://jsfiddle.net/3Km6U/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hover event in jQuery needs 2 callback functions: one when the pointer moves over the item, and one when it leaves:

In your case:

```
jQuery(".cat").hover(
   function() {
      jQuery(this).addClass('show');
   },
   function() {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('show');
   }
);
```

See [Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 2):

Hover has two functions: a hover IN and a hover OUT.

```
jQuery(".cat").hover(
  function() { 
    jQuery(this).addClass('show'); 
  },
  function() { 
    jQuery(this).removeClass('show'); 
  }
);
```

Source: [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Damn! Beat me to it. Fastest gun in the west.

Comment: There's a first time for everything -- first time I got the jump.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery hover function takes two functions.  First is the mouseover function, second is the mouseout function.  To define the mouseout function, just add a comma after the first function and write the second one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".cat").hover(
  function() {
     jQuery(this).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show');
  },
  function() {
     //mouseout stuff
  }
);
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

`.hover` in general takes 2 args function for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event.

However `.hover` also support 1 function arg which basically executes the same handler on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Try like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(".cat").hover(function()  { //mouse enter 
     jQuery(this).addClass('show'); 
  }, 
  function () { //mouse leave 
      jQuery(this).removeClass('show');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to also attach the "mouseout event"

```
$(function(){
$("selector").hover(function(){
//add class here
}, function(){
    //remove class here
});
```

});

basically it takes two arguments
using the hover event is like adding the mouseenter and mouseout events

you could also do this

```
$(selector).mouseenter(function () {  add my class here});
```

and then attach the mouseout

```
$(selector).mouseout(function () { remove the class here});
```